# Rendering starts, but data is black

Tags: rendering

Rendering starts, but data is black

When rendering is started, it starts without problems and the render screen is displayed correctly, but as soon as rendering is finished, the screen turns black. Of course, the data is also black.

I tried export formats such as PNG and mp4, but all remained black.

Other projects render fine, so I think the problem is with this project, but I don't know what the problem is...

The data is so heavy that I couldn't post it on this site, so it would be helpful if you could check it from the Dropbox URL.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5mlrd1gal40j3i6/220301_Purfume_RENDERTEST_light.blend?dl=0

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome.  Can you [edit] your question to include a picture of your compositing workspace?

Comment: Thank you. I added a picture but I don't know this is what you want.. sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the *Image* output instead of *Noisy Image* output from *Render Layers*.

I don't think *Noisy Image* exists in newer versions of Blender, but the socket may still appear under some conditions.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried it and it worked!!! Thank you so much!! I decided to study about Node as soon as possible...! Thanks again!!